# Ubuntu Cannot reinstall coreutils

Tags: environment-variables, nodejs, npm, coreutils

I deleted the `usr/bin/env` file in my Ubuntu16.04 by mistake. Everytime i try to reinstall coreutils with this command: 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils`, i get this error: 
`Reinstallation of coreutils is not possible, it cannot be downloaded`.

I can't use npm because it needs that file.

Please help.

**UPDATE**
I fixed this by downloading the coreutils package from the Ubuntu website,  extracting the zipped files, and copying the env from there. I would still like to know why this happened, in case anyone else has this issue.

Comment: Are you sure `env` was the only thing you removed? doing so doesn't seem to break `apt-get` for me. What does `apt-cache policy coreutils` say?

Comment: Yes it was just `env`.  It says:  ```coreutils:
  Installed: 8.25-2ubuntu3~16.04
  Candidate: 8.25-2ubuntu3~16.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.25-2ubuntu3~16.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```